# Key Vault returns 401 using ManagedIdentityCredential for App Service (Azure.Identity 1.3.0)

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

In my `Startup.cs` I add key vault clients as such:

```
            services.AddAzureClients(s =>
            {
                var keyVaultUri = new Uri(Configuration["KeyVault:Uri"]);
                s.AddCertificateClient(keyVaultUri);
                s.AddSecretClient(keyVaultUri);
                s.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
                {
                    VisualStudioTenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]
                }));
            });
```

Locally, I can authenticatie with the `VisualStudioCredential`. All works fine. When deployed I run into the following error:

[image: Application Insights logs]

The key vault returns a 401 even though I successfully got a token. I am using Access Control on the key vault and it my Managed Identity is a Key Vault Administrator.

What could be going on here and how can I debug this further? I have been stuck on this for a while now.

[image: Role assignment]

EDIT:

Title is misleading and what I thought was happening was not happening. There was no authentication issue but it looked as such in the logs due to another exception I was getting. This was occurring due to the fact my App Service Plan didn't have SSL/TLS functionality required to work with certificates, I needed a more expensive App Service Plan.

Please see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30658#issuecomment-523987878

Comment: Did you use the sdk to get the certificate?https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates#retrieve-a-certificate

Comment: Yes sir, that is what I was using. I figured out my problem very late last night and it was not a key vault issue... What ended up happening was that my App Service Plan was not high enough to use SSL/TLS functionality: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30658#issuecomment-523987878

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your Managed Identity an [access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal) on the Key Vault, not an RBAC access.

RBAC in this case is for management plane operation. Access policies are for data plane operations - which is what you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault

Comment: I can not set an Access Policy as I am using the "Azure role-based access control" permission model. That means that access to the key vault is managed via RBAC. In this case using the role "Key Vault Administrator".

The description for this role mentions being able to perform all data plane operations on the key vault and all objects in it. https://imgur.com/tI3oAqi

Comment: ah ok, you didnt say that :)

Comment: But I did now. Thanks for the answer anyway. :)